# Access Event Hub inside a Virtual Network

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-virtual-network

I have got an Event Hub that is currently inside a Virtual Network. I have got my public IP added to a Network Security Rule, however when I try and connect to my Event Hub I get the following error:

`Ip has been prevented to connect to the endpoint`

I have looked at the following guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-ip-filtering
And this does work, however, is there any benefit to putting the Event Hub inside a Virtual Network vs filtering IPs following the steps in the guide?

The requirements I would like to meet is being able to lock an Event Hub down so that specific Public IPs can read and write to Event Hub, and allow an Azure Function to trigger off Event Hub.

Here is my VNET Config:
[image]

The Security Group (`allowSpecificRanges`) has my public IP in.

Am I missing a step here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can secure the event hub by either a firewall of a virtual network.

After that you can connect the function the virtual network of the event hub or create a Ip address policy in firewall which will allow Ip address of the function.

This can be configured this under `Networking` tag in event hub.
[image]
Select the `selected network`.
[image]
After that either add virtual network or add firewall rule.

Also make sure that the function you will use is of premium tier.

Refer the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-ip-filtering) for more info